# How do I get a link to return false if clicked once, but return true if clicked again?

Tags: jquery, html, css

By styling default, the parent menu items are hidden from view. When they're hovered via a mouse, the class "show" is added.

However, I would like a similar concept to work for tablets, which relies on tapping or double clicking. I want the class "show" to be added when a parent menu item is clicked one, and if it's clicked again, return true and open the link.

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
  <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.show {
  background:orange;
  color:white;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#nav .wsite-menu-item-wrap a').on('click', function() {

  if($("#nav .wsite-menu-item-wrap a").hasClass("show")){
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
    $(this).addClass('show');
  }

});
```

Comment: Code after return statement is unreachable. You need to add class before you exit the function.

Comment: @Weebs - you also have a syntax error in your class definitions, should be `<li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap"><a href="#">Home</a></li>`.   You are missing a closing double quote on your class names.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly note that logic flow exits the current function when a `return` statement is hit. Therefore your current `addClass()` won't do anything.

You will also need to remove the `show` class from the `a` elements in siblings of the parent `li` to the one which was clicked.

From there your logic, using `hasClass()`, is correct. Try this:

```js
$('#nav .wsite-menu-item-wrap a').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass("show")) {
    console.log('subsequent click');
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('show').closest('li').siblings().find('a').removeClass('show');
    console.log('first click');
  }
});
```

```css
.show {
  background: orange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function that add a class if it doesn't exist or remove it if it already exists

```js
$('#nav .wsite-menu-item-wrap a').on('click', function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
.show {
  background:orange;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li class="wsite-menu-item-wrap"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</div>
```